# Как возрващать данные из api

Tags: веб-программирование, rest

Насколько мне известно, при построении сервиса, следует выбирать формат данных, которые будут возвращать его api и всегда возвращать данные именно в этом формате.

Но что если api возвращает, например, счетчик новых сообщений(не чат) и больше ничего? Не будет ли правильнее вернуть только счетчик, чтобы его не распаковывать, например из json, а сразу положить в нужную часть html? Или на фронте всегда будет распаковщик json, который все будет распаковывать и нужно все же все запаковывать в json даже такие мелочи чтобы на фронте не возникло ошибок?

Comment: *"Не будет ли правильнее вернуть только счетчик,"* --- ну тут два вопроса: а что, если ничего не вернётся? никакого счётчика. ошибка была во время запроса......... и второе: окей, допустим нет единого формата, а api большое, на 1000 разных запросов. Что, все эти 1000 запросов по своему обрабатывать каждый раз? не слишком ли это сложно

Comment: Одиночное число или строка даже без фигурных скобок и массивов является валидным JSON-значением согласно [спецификации](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).
А дальше отталкивайтесь от потребностей вашего бэкенда и фронтэнда. Тут нет единственно верного способа.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну вот я пишу в респонс 0-если нет сообщений, счетчик-если сообщения есть, -1-если ошибка. Если приходит -1, просто счетчик на фронте не обновится.

Comment: @Nofate получается я могу создать енкодер и енкодить в респонс простые данные, например, счетчики, если не хочу платить за декодинг, а енкодить в респонс более сложные сущности, в формате json. Мой енкодер не ругается когда я пытаюсь енкодить простые числа и позволяет себя использовать для енкодинга более сложных сущностей в формат {"key":"value"}. Стало быть ничего страшного нет, что api счетчика сообщений вернет простую цифру?

Comment: *"-1-если ошибка"* --- а теперь расширяем подобный эффект. При запросе списка какого-либо, в случае ошибки возвращаем `unknown`, при запросе пользователя и ошибки - `null`, в случае запроса даты и ошибки `0000-00-00`, при запросе координат и ошибки `-111111, +111111`, при запросе цвета и ошибки - `#deep-brown` и т.д...... вам не кажется что это черезчур усложнено? Когда достаточно оперировать статусами и единым возвращаемым объектом `{ 'error': { 'message': 'xxx'}}` ? ........ и как быть, если тип ошибки может быть разный и реагировать на них нужно по разному? ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  я согласен, что кейс который вы приводите выглядит не очень, но я говорю немного о другом. Когда возвращаются более сложные типы данных чем счетчик сообщений(int), конечно нужно его оборачивать в единый формат. Мой вопрос немного о другом. Стоит ли платить за распаковку счетчика?

Comment: *"Стало быть ничего страшного нет, что api счетчика сообщений вернет простую цифру?"*  --- надо вообще понимать для чего api нужно. Если кто-то другой будет пользоваться эти api - то он, мягко говоря, очень удивится получать на некоторые запросы нестандартизированный на весь api ответ и просто уйдёт.....А если это чисто внутреннее, то надо понимать, что вешать абсолютно на всё запросы api - это неразумно. И, возможно, есть другие решения. Например простой запрос ajax или если это чат и работа на сокетах - то брокер сообщений просто отдаёт эту информацию и API тут вообще ни при чём

Comment: @Quester *"Стоит ли платить за распаковку счетчика?"* --- а у вас счётчик на гигабайты?)) что именно вы платите, кроме как 0,00001сек?)) Вы пытаетесь экономить, как принято говорить, на спичках. В то время как в системах происходят гораздо более сложные процессы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вот про ajax я как раз думаю, но разве ему не нужно обратиться к uri который вернет ему какие то данные?

Comment: Нужно, но это не обязательно должен быть api.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151691/discussion-between-quester-and--).